# Unable to handle onbeforeunload event using Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, onbeforeunload

I have the following callback for my `onbeforeUnload` event in one of my service.
In my `app.run` block I have:

`window.onbeforeunload = Services.beforeWindowClose;`

and this method is in a service:

```
this.beforeWindowClose = function (event) {
            var currentState = $state.current.name;
            if (currentState !== constant.LOGOUT) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("close");
                if (Utilities.isSavePending)
                    event.returnValue = constant.MSG;
            }
        }
```

In my controllers I have :

```
$scope.$on("close", function () {
            Utilities.isSavePending = vm.save; //sets it to true
        })
```

Now given the events are synchronous in angular, this code should give me a popup on window close. However,this directly closes my window.

My intention is that whenever the user closes window, I raise an event and see if there is any unsaved data in my controller. If there is some unsaved data, the browser should not close and give a popup, while if there is no unsaved data, the browser should close.

Am I doing or understanding something wrong?

Comment: Are you saying you don't get the browser default confirm dialog? Expected behavior and problem is not very clear

Comment: Also, try to `return constant.MSG`, cause some browsers need this

Comment: yes charlietfl, you got me correct. I am not getting the popup. The expected behaviour is to get popup only when isSavePending turns out to be true.

Comment: @dloeda returning msg didn't help either.

Comment: Did you double check both conditions are correct and `event.returnValue = constant.MSG;`code is executing?

Comment: @dloeda thats exactly where the issue is. Once the event is raised the value is correcly set from the controller. Therafter, I expect the browser to come and check my `if(Utilities.isSavePending)` condition. The browser does come here but hovering on`if(Utilities.isSavePending)` shows nothing and then the `if(Utilities.isSavePending)` is never executed and the browser just closes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your module `run` function, you must declare `beforeunload` event this way :

```
.run(['$window', 'Utilities', function($window, Utilities) {  
  $window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e)         
     // Place code here
  };       
});
```

NOT this way :

```
.run(['$window', 'Utilities', function($window, Utilities) {  
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {         
     // Place code here
    };
}]);
```

Here is a snippet to use `onbeforeunload` event with Angular.

> **Note:** depending on your browser, snippet won't work after you click *Save item* button and you try to close this window. You'll then need to paste the code in your own project.

**Additional information**

Recent HTML specifications now prevent customization of the popup message, a generic message is displayed instead.

It is therefore always possible to prevent navigation but it is no longer possible to specify a custom message

This always works on IE11 but it should not last long (until the next update).

HTML Specs about this :
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#unloading-documents

Chrome/Safari docs about this :
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'Utilities', 'ItemService', function($scope, Utilities, ItemService) {
    // Expose Utilities to make pending state available in template
    $scope.Utilities = Utilities;
    // Use item service to save our item
    $scope.save = function() {
      ItemService.saveItem();
    }
    $scope.fireCloseEvent = function() {
      $scope.$emit('close');
    }
    $scope.$on('close', function(event) {
      Utilities.toggleSavePending();
    });
  }])
  .factory('ItemService', ['Utilities', function(Utilities) {
    return {
      saveItem: function() {
        // ...
        // Toggle global save pending state
        Utilities.toggleSavePending();
      }
    }
  }])
  .factory('Utilities', function() {
    var savePending = false;

    return {
      toggleSavePending: function() {
        savePending = !savePending;
      },
      isSavePending: function() {
        return savePending;
      }
    }
  })
  .run(['$window', 'Utilities', function($window, Utilities) {

    $window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
      // If save pending state is truthy, prevent browser window from closing
      if (Utilities.isSavePending()) {
        var message = 'Warning! Save pending...';
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e) {
          e.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
      }
    });

  }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController">

  <button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="Utilities.isSavePending()">Save item</button>
  <button ng-click="fireCloseEvent()">Fire Close Event</button>
  <div ng-if="Utilities.isSavePending()">A message should be displayed when you close the window</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I have used the event successfully at many places. However, in this case I would like the popup to display only when there are some changed data in my application, which I keep track using the Service variable. But for some reason the final `if(Utilities.isSavePending)` condition seems not to work at all

Comment: Did you inject `Utilities` in module `run` function

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari I've updated my answer with a full example (controller, Utilities service)

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari Here is my final update with decoupled code (ItemService, Utilities, Controller)

Comment: The same code doesn't work if I try to get the `save` status inside the `onbeforeunload` callback using event mechanism.

Comment: I am running it into my app and it doesn't work when you try figuring all the condition after the window close has been initiated, i.e inside the callback as I posted in my original question. If possible try executing the code once, it might give you some hint.

Comment: You must use `$window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) ` to listen to `beforeunload` event or it won't work. Answer updated

Comment: Yes it did help with `$window and addEventListener`. Any idea why it might not be working with my original way. Also though it shows the popup now, it still displays its own default message and not picking message provided in `e.return = 'Message to show'`

Comment: About default message, checkout Additional information in my answer, I'm explaining why custom message do not work anymore on most recent browsers ;)