# How to trigger a function after I close or refresh the browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sql-server, angular

I want to update my data on SQL server database after I directly closed or refresh the browser.

Here's my code:

```
$scope.default = function () {
   //Update the data to default value which is "Active = 0"
}

$scope.change = function () {
   //Update the data to "Active = 1"
}
```

I tried using `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` but it's not working when I directly close the browser. This is working when I only refresh the browser:

```
window.onbeforeunload = $scope.default();
```

I'm using the latest Chrome and Mozilla. I also want to know the limitation of `window.onbeforeunload` since my page can access using mobile does this will still trigger my function when it directly closed browser on mobile.

Comment: Is it because of asynchronous function inside the window.onbeforeunload that makes it seems like not triggering?

Comment: @holydragon Nope, it's working properly when the browser is refreshed only. But when I close or change the URL to other page my function is not working. It didn't update my data on database.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132997/unable-to-handle-onbeforeunload-event-using-angular-service

Comment: Appreciate your help @holydragon I found the answer on other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I found a solution on my question. I used the below codes:

```
        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            e.returnValue = true;
            $scope.default();
            return 'onbeforeunload';
        }
```

This solution is to make `onbeforeunload` work on Chrome. However I want to know if this will still run the function if I run my page to mobile and to other browser/s.